# Помогите пожалуйста правильно считать числа с плавающей точкой из файла формата txt

Tags: c++

Как можно перевести текстовый файл состоящий из чисел с плавающей точкой в числовой массив. Например Есть файл * .txt Каждый столбец должен быть отдельным массивом, чтобы потом можно было с данным массивов проводить различные математические операции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут не принято делать домашнее задание за других.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если там запятая - например, так:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<double> x, y;
    ifstream in("data");
    string s;
    while(getline(in,s))
    {
        size_t pos;
        while((pos = s.find(',')) != s.npos) s.replace(pos,1,".");
        double a, b;
        istringstream ss(s);
        if (ss >> a >> b)
        {
            x.push_back(a);
            y.push_back(b);
            cout << a << "  " << b << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо Harry, программа работает, но она выводит числа в первом столбце не так как на той картинке что я прикрепил а дописывает е-6. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить? 
Пример: она выводит -3,486е-6 а должно быть -0,000003486

Comment: Ну если это так важно, напишите  вместо `cout << a` - `cout << fixed << setprecision(12) << a` - это чисто проблемы вывода...

Comment: спасибо, все работает!)

Comment: я так понял что х и у это векторы.
х.push_back (a) здесь занчення а записывается в вектор х
y.push_back (b) здесь значение бы записывается в вектор в
я правильно понимаю?
Могу ли я потом данные из вектора х записать в массив t[], а данные из вектора y записать в массив V[]?
Мне нужно чтобы первый столбец был в массиве t[], а второй в массиве V[] .
Я думаю, что для этого мне понадобится цикл for.
Сначала с помощью цикла for я буду записывать данные из вектора х в массив t[] а затем с помощью второго аналогичный цикл буду записывать данные из вектора y в массив V[].

Comment: Ну вектора - это же и есть массивы в C++. Вы же к данным `vector<double> x` обращаетесь так же - как к `x[i]`. Если уж так нужны массивы - пишите прямо в массив, минуя вектор. Но писать в вектор, чтоб потом в массив - это как... ну, не знаю... поехать на Мерседесе **менять** его на "Запорожец"...

Comment: просто в условии задачи сказано что входные данные должны быть представлены в виде двух массивов (входные данные нужно считать с вышеупомянутого файла)

Comment: считать данные из файла и записать их в отдельные векторы получилось, а как сделать так чтоб программа в векторе х искала значение и выводила его на экран (там получается массив с положительных и отрицательное значения, причем они там чередуются, например идет десять положительных значений а затем пятнадцать отрицательных значений, мне нада чтоб программа искала последнее с положительных значений и выводила его на экран затем искала в векторе у значение которое находится на той же позиции что то значение из вектора х которое выводится на экран.

Comment: когда она найдет несколько положительных значений чтоб она вывела последнее из них а потом когда она наткнется на несколько отрицательное значений чтоб она их пропустила и потом когда наткнется снова на положительные то чтоб вывела последнее из них. получается цикл который должен выполняться пока не закончатся элементы в векторе х.

Comment: Лучше оформляйте это отдельным вопросом, на комментарий это не тянет :)

Comment: я уже оформил. спасибо